# The amount of training data generated in Rasa

Tags: keras, rasa-core, rasa

I have a bunch of intents defined in my `nlu.md`. The file is 241 lines long. I also have a domain.yml file and a stories.md file.

I then hit `rasa train` on the terminal and things start running. This is the first few lines;

```
Epoch 1/100
763/763 [==============================] - 1s 736us/sample - loss: 2.6756 - acc: 0.3486
Epoch 2/100
763/763 [==============================] - 0s 168us/sample - loss: 2.2360 - acc: 0.5007
Epoch 3/100
763/763 [==============================] - 0s 166us/sample - loss: 1.8602 - acc: 0.5007
Epoch 4/100
763/763 [==============================] - 0s 171us/sample - loss: 1.7426 - acc: 0.5007
Epoch 5/100
763/763 [==============================] - 0s 166us/sample - loss: 1.6763 - acc: 0.5007
```

I understand that these lines of code are the output from keras but I wonder ... where does the number 763 come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, it's the number of batches

Comment: But what is the reasoning of getting 763 batches when the `nlu.md` file only has 241 lines in it?

Comment: number of lines in the story file doesn't correspond to number of training examples for dialogue policy